# Toggle images using ajax

Tags: jsf, primefaces

I have 4 buttons, each button will display one image using Ajax.

```
<h:form>
            <h:commandButton value="Click" action="#{userAjaxData.toggleStatus}">
                <f:ajax render="Family" />
            </h:commandButton>
            <h:commandButton value="Click" action="#{userAjaxData.toggleStatus}">
                <f:ajax render="Karam"/>
            </h:commandButton>
            <h:commandButton value="Click" action="#{userAjaxData.toggleStatus}">
                <f:ajax render="Memo"/>
            </h:commandButton>
            <h:commandButton value="Click" action="#{userAjaxData.toggleStatus}">
                <f:ajax render="Baba"/>
            </h:commandButton>

            <h:panelGroup id="Family">
                <p:graphicImage library="images/img" name="family.png" id="FamilyImg" rendered="#{userAjaxData.status}"/>
            </h:panelGroup>
            <h:panelGroup id="Karam">
                <p:graphicImage library="images/img" name="Karam.png" id="KaramImg" rendered="#{userAjaxData.status}"/>
            </h:panelGroup>
            <h:panelGroup id="Memo">
                <p:graphicImage library="images/img" name="memo.png" id="MemoImg" rendered="#{userAjaxData.status}"/>
            </h:panelGroup>
            <h:panelGroup id="Baba">
                <p:graphicImage library="images/img" name="baba.png" id="BabaImg" rendered="#{userAjaxData.status}"/>
            </h:panelGroup>
        </h:form>
```

My manged bean:

```
@ManagedBean(name = "userAjaxData", eager = true)
@SessionScoped
public class UserAjaxData implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    private boolean status = false;

public void toggleStatus() {
        status = true;
    }

    public boolean isStatus() {
        return status;
    }

    public void setStatus(boolean status) {
        this.status = status;
    }}
```

when I click any button It will display the related image, so if I click the first one it will display the first image, and the second button will display the second image but the first image will not removed. I just need one way to display one image each time I click button. so if I click the first button then the second button should the second image displayed and the first one disappear.

How can I mange it?

Comment: Does it work using a plain jsf graphicImage? If not, it is not PrimeFaces related

Comment: your code is very weird... The fact that the first image is not changed is because you do not `render` it in the other buttons. But if you did, they'd show all at once since they share the same status field. So your code is kind of weird

Comment: @kukeltje my code lets each button display one image. So if I click 4 buttons I will get 4 images in the page. I just want to toggle between the images like on and off. When I click on button only the image related to that button should display and the other image should be disappered. What do you mean if it works with plain graphicImage? Do you main graphicImage without panelGroub? If yes then it will not work without panelGroup.

Comment: an `h:graphicImage`.  And try reloading your page. You'll see all the images get the same state

Comment: @kukeltje ok I see what you mean.aybe set the state back to false in the ManagedBean. So just the image related to button will have render=true. But we still unable to display only one image since othrr button not forced to be clicked when click other button

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your usecase is really that simple, I would recommend using only **one** always rendered `<h:graphicImage />` (no need for PrimeFaces *GraphicImage* in this case) and set the appropriate image to show in the backing bean via ajax instead of one or multiple toggle statuses with something like this:

```xml
<h:form id="form">
    <h:commandButton
        id="familyButton"
        action="#{toggleImageView.setImage('family.png')}"
        value="Family"
    >
        <f:ajax render="image" />
    </h:commandButton>
    <h:commandButton
        id="karamButton"
        action="#{toggleImageView.setImage('karam.png')}"
        value="Karam"
    >
        <f:ajax render="image" />
    </h:commandButton>
    <h:commandButton
        id="memoButton"
        action="#{toggleImageView.setImage('memo.png')}"
        value="Memo"
    >
        <f:ajax render="image" />
    </h:commandButton>
    <h:commandButton
        id="babaButton"
        action="#{toggleImageView.setImage('baba.png')}"
        value="Baba"
    >
        <f:ajax render="image" />
    </h:commandButton>
    <br />
    <h:graphicImage
        id="image"
        library="image/img"
        name="#{toggleImageView.image}"
    />
</h:form>
```

```java
@ManagedBean
@RequestScoped
public class ToggleImageView {

    private String image;

    @PostConstruct
    public void initialize() {
        image = "family.png";
    }

    public String getImage() {
        return image;
    }

    public void setImage(String image) {
        this.image = image;
    }
}
```

Just adapt to your needs.